# I cannot look a new item inserted in another page, I need refresh the page to look it in xhtml

Tags: java, jpa, primefaces, ejb

I m developing a Java EE 7 application with: JPA, EJB and JSF (Primefaces).

I have 3 pages, one is the index.xhtml, other is insert.xhtml and the last is list.xhtml. The flow is : when I insert a new item in the insert.xhtml, I need when I navigate to the list.xhtml, this page show the new Item inserted in the index.xhtml, but this not occour, I need refresh the page to look the new Item inserted in the another xhtml page. So my question is :

**What I need to do to look the new Item inserted with out to refresh the list.xhtml page?**

I have the following components :

- JPA with DAO // this is ok.
- ONE Staless EJB
  `@ManagedBean`
  `@ViewScoped`
- 3 xhtml pages : index.xhml , insert.xhtml and list.xhtml. // The index page has 2 links to the anothers xhtml pages.

Comment: Please read [ask] and act accordingly

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using one @ViewScoped bean for all 3 pages. The lifecycle of viewScoped bean is tide up to a single view (or page). That means, when you navigate to new page, a new instance of viewScoped bean is created (and data in old viewScoped bean are lost). Have you tried to use @SessionScoped bean??

Comment: Hi, the problem was, update the List<Object > listUsers;

Answer (score 0):

the problem was, update the

`List<Object > listUsers`,

I forgot use the add and remove methods from the **List Java Collection**

```
listUsers.add( newUser )
listUsers.remove( newUser )
```

And whole work fine.

Thanks.